# Is there a media center application that uses the native gui?

Tags: media, media-manager, home-theatre

I've tried a fair number of media center apps like Boxee or XBMC. They all seem to use their own UI. Is there one that uses the native UI, more like rhythmbox or banshee?

I'm looking for something that has the library features of one of the more fully featured media centers I've listed. E.g. features like getting actor and director names, and linking to other media in the collection that shares these attributes.

E.g. If I have The Birds in my collection I could click on Alfred Hitchcock and see Rear Window or whatever.

Comment: Please edit your answer to say what your media center should do. There are different kinds.

Comment: XBMC supports this the new latest beta 3 eden preview is just perfect .... here is a video i made ...

http://youtu.be/q7Yl-V_PHcc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer to this is NO, there is not a full pledged media centre using native gui (GTK+).

Answer (score 4):

It seems [Ubuntu TV](https://askubuntu.com/q/94148/18612) will offer a media center that uses an interface based on Unity, which is as close as I think you will get to a media center that looks native. However, it's not available just yet, unless you want to try downloading and compiling the [code](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntutv) yourself, but I have no idea how to go about doing that or making sure it works properly afterwards.