# What is Ubuntu For Android?

Tags: android, ubuntu-for-android

The question is in the title, but can anyone provide some details on what it is, how it works, and when it will be available?

Comment: Unofficially (I assume), it's [been available for quite some time](http://androlinux.com/android-ubuntu-development/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-android/).

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android

Comment: Read here:http://www.pcpro.co.uk/news/373024/canonical-puts-ubuntu-on-android-smartphones and here: http://www.extremetech.com/computing/119031-canonical-reveals-ubuntu-for-android and on slashdot: http://mobile.slashdot.org/story/12/02/21/1744201/canonical-puts-ubuntu-on-android-smartphones

Comment: Are you asking this question seriously? There are tons of information both on the official page and in the media on the web, and I fail to believe you can't get it ;)

Comment: @rafalcieslak Yep, it's exactly as serious as [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94148/what-is-ubuntu-tv). I can go Google it but we all still need a good destination page for an answer. Ask Ubuntu is a natural choice for this, and we can't just ignore it, can we? I briefly considered asking 'how do I shot web' instead but settled on this question. Hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not a "mobile version" of Ubuntu.

It's a special build of the Ubuntu OS that can be installed on Android dual-core phone, with this you can attach a HDMI monitor (and I think a bluetooth keyboard and mouse) and use your smartphone as a computer with Ubuntu.

As an extra, from that desktop you can access to phone data (like addressbook) and send / receive calls.

I think that this image clarify what is it:[image]

Official page for more info: 
http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android

Comment: A lot of very relevant links containing more details have unfortunately been posted in the question comments instead of in answers. It'd be great if you could edit your answer to include a link to the [official page](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android) for Ubuntu for Android, and maybe add some additional details for the other linked news articles above as appropriate. I think that'd really help polish this answer up!

Answer (score 2):

It's similar to the Motorola devices webtop app that recent devices have.

You dock it and use your mouse and keyboard to use it as a desktop.

Coincidentally, Motorola has been using Ubuntu for a year on webtops.

Comment: Except webtop is highly limited, whereas Ubuntu for Android aims to give users a full desktop environment

Comment: True ...
what i meant was its not something new....