# How do I use Ubuntu for Android?

Tags: android, hdmi, ubuntu-for-android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Ubuntu For Android?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106273/what-is-ubuntu-for-android)

I'd like to know something more about Ubuntu for Android and its features and its date of release, if I can use it already and how. I've read the [official Ubuntu page about it](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android), but I'd like to know how to use it, if you need a dock HDMI to use it, etc.

Comment: I want it. I simply want it.

Answer (score 2):

This video will help you:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=gUXUjjg9qQ0

Read this too:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/02/ubuntu-for-android-announced/

I think that when it will ready, you can read it here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android

Comment: Ubuntu for Android is a hybrid device for quad-core (or minimally, dual-core) phones which let you dock your phone and get a full Ubuntu desktop that has all the information (contacts, calendar, web history, photos, etc.) from your Android phone. (taken from mail by Nathan Haines)